# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden - When I run a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, uwp-xaml

I started developing an app that using universal windows technology as a website.
I am working with Visual Studio 2017
When I am running my created website I got the following message
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden - The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory
I tried to deal with the problem, with the suggestions I found on the internet but unfortunately, they don't help me.
I will be very happy if you can help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzrtm.png)

Comment: The default role for a client connect to a server is GUEST which gives limited access to files on server.  You should avoid reading/writing to file system on server.   Either use the clients file system, or a network drive where both client and server have full access.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from your website's host. You have to contact them in order to fix that error